# Manifest Error App Crashes

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest, logcat

I reinstalled Windows on my pc and tried to open my old project with a newer version of android studio.

This is my Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.linkr.chat"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Login" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

When i change the line android:name=".Login" to android:name=".Chat", the activity Chat opens up and doesn't crash. But i want Login to open first, so i use android:name=".Login", and if i then click on the button to open the chat it crashes.

The error i got from logcat was:

```
    Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.linkr.chat/com.linkr.chat.Chat}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Why does it want me to declare this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wants you to declare the `.Chat` activity, you guessed it right. Right now only `.Login` activity is declared. You should add this line right below the `</activity>` in your manifest file to declare `.Chat` as well:

```
<activity android:name=".Chat"/>
```

This way there will be two actvities in your application: `.Login` and `.Chat`. Now both of them can be accessed from your application by `startActivity` method. Every new activity you create should be declared in this manner.

Comment: omg THANK YOU! :D i can't believe i was so dumb. I'm very new to Java and Android. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

All Activities in a project need to be declared in the Manifest.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Login" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Chat" >
</application>
```

Are you starting it from an intent in the "Login" Activity? AFAIK, it only asks you to declare the activities that are actually referenced.

Comment: Thank y'all! :D Declaring it fixed it^^

Answer (score 0):

Declare this activity in your manifest file.

```
  <activity android:name="com.linkr.chat.Chat" > </activity>
```

And your problem should be long gone!